# replace method for python strings

Tags: python, string, immutability

I have a string S = 'spam'

When I use the method replace as S.replace('pa', 'xx')

```
S.replace('pa', 'xx')
```

The output I get is -

```
Out[1044]: "sxxm's"
```

Why then are the python strings known to be immutable ?

Comment: Who says the string object `S` references itself is altered? You got a *new string* back, which was echoed.

Comment: Try `T = S.replace('pa', 'xx')` and you'll see that `S` is unaltered afterwards. [*"Return a copy of the string with all occurrences of substring old replaced by new."*](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.replace)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
S = 'spam'
S.replace('pa', 'xx')
print S
```

You will get the same string `'spam'`

Answer (score -1):

You are not saving the return value.

```
Snew = S.replace('pa', 'xx')
```

should work